# mediawiki article check if exists

Tags: php, mediawiki, article

I'm using a mediawiki with multilanguage. i used same database with the prefix.

I want to make some changes like this;

for example i have en.wiki.com and de.wiki.com

My all articles in de.wiki.com i will translate them later. but when visitors visit the en.wiki.com if the article doesn't exist they want to see de.wiki.com article.

Sorry for my bad English.

i have de.wiki.com/asd page
en.wiki.com/asd doesn't exists so they must see de.wiki.com/asd page article.

can you help about this ?

Comment: Do you mean you're using [Extension:Multilang](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Multilang)?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Language Extension Bundle](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_Language_Extension_Bundle). By using those extensions, the people accessing your wiki will see (by default) the article in the language their wiki is in and there is a button for changing the active language.

Let's say that you have a german user and she tries to access wiki.com/RandomArticle, there is no german translation of the article and the wiki therefore shows the user the english version. That's what you want right? You can even have inner wiki links that work like that!

```
[[Special:MyLanguage/NameOfPage]]
```